# Can the behaviour of the Ropsten Test net be compared to that of the main net?

Tags: solidity, gas, ropsten, gas-limit, gas-estimate

can be assumed, that a contract behaves in the same way on the Ropsten Test test as well as on the main net, in terms of gas consumption for example?

(I think, that the gas price might be different?)

Are there examples that show, that there is a major difference (for example when using dependencies like deployed libraries, that are not available on another net).

Thanks.

Comment: Good question, I deployed an identical smart contract on Ropsten and my own private network. The gas usage on Ropsten was much higher. Unfortunately,  I did't had enough time to figure out why.

Comment: Hmmm ok, as long as the test network has higher gas usage than the mainnet, then it's good, but still, same results would be nicer... thank you for sharing your experience

Comment: I've been wondering this for awhile, did you happen to find a source or more info?

Answer (score 0):

after deploying a couple of times on testnet (Rinkeby) and Mainnet, I can say, that the contracts will behave in the same way. Still, gas will be a completely other topic.
You can try to estimate it in advance by checking the consumption on testnet. If you are using standard functions (like from ERC721, ERC20 etc.) then try to find that function on a deployed contract to see how much gas they are using up.

And: run automated tests locally and on testnet as much as you can ;)